# Redis: create a ttl'd ('expires') key if one does not exist with python?

Tags: python, redis

I'd like to use redis to implement a cool-down mechanism: a list of items that will expire after some time (say 60 seconds), but only get created if they do not already exist.

it sounds like I need a setnx (set if not exists), with a ttl. is it possible to do so with the redis python api?

Comment: did you check cache.get and cache.set? it work for one item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just use `nx` and `ex` kwargs for `.set()` method:

```
r.set('foo', 'bar', ex=10, nx=True)
```

Comment: as `.set()` always return None, how you know if the set was successful or not?